# Solution for checking sound levels between recording sessions

Tags: editing

We have had problems with a professional recording company that records for us all year long. We piece audio bits together and sometimes the levels are off and the final product sounds off when put older and newer clips next to each other. We don't record any music, just talking. We hand them "scripts", or sentences split by file, for the talent to say and they return the wav files.

Is there software out there that can analyze a sound file, comparing it to an "original sample", and tell if the levels are off?

Is there a better way to ensure the audio levels always match from session to session?

I have no experience in recording. I am a programmer so I know a lot about computers.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like an ongoing vocal recording the assumption would be that the settings and environment would be the same each time. This isn't very technical but it would be the first thing I would ask - that they use a standard config.

If you are trying to correct after the fact, a compressor can help you bring levels up to a standard.

Or if you have ProTools, Cubase or decent tools, you can also bring all the levels to a consistent standard really easily.

But really - get it specified with the provider, they should be able to sort it.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. When I said levels, I was referring to the settings of an equalizer, not volume. The recordings can be "bassy" or sound like she is in a tunnel. Can ProTools fix this?

Comment: ProTools probably can, yes - there are some things it just can't fix but it is amazingly powerful. For all future recordings, though - get them to stick to a standard set of levels. Makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tools not only can resolve your equalize problem, but any volume problem too.
Unfortanelly, even with preset parameters for a envelope equalizer effect for example, u have to do a little audio training to get the same sound all time by finning tuning the output. U should look waves and spectrums too. Better try to **rec always in same conditions**, to avoid this. Hope this helps a little.

hmm.. probly u, with a programmer experience should create/run/find a script that will do exactly what u asked for(with Pro Tools or without it): "*analyze a sound file, comparing it to an "original sample", and tell if the levels are off*/ok and correct if so"

Editing is the art of timelines. (a word from a video-man to a program-man)